# How do I only allow one image to be highlighted?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have checkmarks inside my tableview cell to indicate which cell is clicked. Instead of clicking the cell, the buttons will be clicked. I can get the information from each cell and change the image, but the problem is when I click one and then click the other, both cell buttons are highlighted. Instead I only want the latest button clicked to be highlighted. Only one button can be highlighted at a a time.

```
func selected(sender: UIButton){
    let buttonTag = sender.tag

    if (sender.selected)
    {
        sender.selected = false
        print("none")
    }
    else
    {
        sender.selected = true
        print(animal[buttonTag])


    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: animalcell = animal.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellanimal") as! animalcell
    cell.check.addTarget(self, action: "selected:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.check.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.check.setImage(UIImage(named: "bttnnonhighlight"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.check.setImage(UIImage(named: "buttonhighlight"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
    cell.check.selected = false
    previouslySelected = cell.check
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to all the buttons. Then when the user taps on one calling the payment selected method, deselect all of them then reselect the one tapped on (the sender).

Comment: How would I keep a reference of all the buttons? The number of buttons will change for every user.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remember the one being clicked, and uncheck it before you check the newly clicked one.

```
func selected(sender: UIButton){
    if (sender != previouslySelected) {
       previouslySelected.selected = false
    }
    let buttonTag = sender.tag

    if (sender.selected)
    {
        sender.selected = false
        print("none")
    }
    else
    {
        sender.selected = true
        previouslySelected = sender
        print(animal[buttonTag])
    }
}
```

You will always only have one selected

Comment: Works, but when I select, scroll down, and scroll back, it is unselected

Comment: that's completely unrelated to having only one button selected, if it happens with this 'solution', I bet it also happens with multiple selection?

Comment: you have to keep selected state of the cell and highlight the checkbox when recreating a cell which should be selected

Comment: Please check out my updated code. The change is the very last line. I am still stuck because of the problem I stated in my previous comment.

Comment: that last line does not make sense at all, always use minimal compilable examples, put in some effort

Answer (score 0):

Cancel the latest selected button status before selecting next cell button in the `UITableView` delegate:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
        // Cancel seleted status of lastest cell button
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UITableViewDelegate` has a method named `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath?`


in this func you can get current selected cell via `indexPathForSelectedRow`, it is property of `UITableView`, now you can uncheck the last selected cell

Answer (score 0):

Make global variable: `BOOL selectedIndex`.

In your `selected:` method

```
- (IBAction)selected:(UIButton *)button{
    UIView *view = button.superview;
    while (view && ![view isMemberOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        view = view.superview;
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = view;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And in your `tableView:willDisplayCell:` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    BOOL shouldSetSelected = (selectedIndex == indexPath.row);
    [cell.check setSelected:shouldSetSelect];
}
```